# Finding boundary with given number and a list

Tags: python, algorithm

I was given this problem. Given a list of percentage = [0.1,0.1,0.8] and number = 9, find all possible list (boundary of each element is 0.25 to 10, increment = 0.25) that multiply with the percentage list ,sum those number together and round to 1 decimal place must be equal to number = 9. I use brute force algorithm to solve this problem with the assistance of itertools product. but brute force this way is pretty slow. I'm trying to find a boundary (upper and lower boundary in range(lower boundary,upper boundary,25) for my 'for loop'. Can you guys suggest me a way to find it?

```
    import itertools
    
    ranges = []
    
    n = int(input()) #number of element in percentage list

    percent = []
    
    for i in range(n):
        percent.append(float(input())) #input the percentage list
    
    total = float(input()) #the number mentioned above

    for i in range(n):
        ranges.append(range(25,1025,25)) #find boundary for this line

    for xs in itertools.product(*ranges):
        avg = 0
        for i in range(n):
            avg += xs[i]*percent[i]    
        if avg < (total*100+5) and avg >= (total*100-5):
            for each in xs:
                print(each/100, end = ' ')
            print()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit hard for me to explain algorithm in concise words T.T

So sufficient explanation is stated in the following code comments.

Basic idea is that this is be done in a recursive way (DFS, depth first search). The function should be something like `recursion(percent_list, result_list, target)`.

- Initially, it should be `recursion([0.1, 0.1, 0.8], [], 9)`
- If we try the first value to be 3.25, then we update target value by 9 - 3.25*0.1 = 8.675. So we next call `recursion([0.1, 0.8], [3.25], 8.675)`;
- Then, we try the second value to be 4.00, then update target value by 8.675 - 4.0*0.1 = 8.275. So call `recursion([0.8], [3.25, 4.0], 8.275)`;
- Finally, we try the third value, and only 9.75, 10 is valid, since the summed up value are 8.525 and 8.725, respectly, and could round up to 9. So we append results `[3.25, 4.0, 9.75]` and `[3.25, 4.0, 10.0]` to result list.
- After that, we try the second value to be 0.25, ..., 3.75, 4.25, 4.5, ..., 10.
- Try first value to be 0.25, ..., 3.0, 3.5, 3.75, ..., 10.

To avoid too much recursion calls, we need to calculate the valid value could be appended to results every time, to cut the branches that's impossible.

The actual function signature is somehow differnt, to achieve round up.

```py
import numpy as np

def recursion(percent_list, value_list, previous_results, target, tolerate_lower, tolerate_upper, result_list):
    #         change      , 0.25 ~ 10 , change,         , change, 0.5 = 9.5-9   , 0.4999 < 9-8.5, your answer
    # init:   [0.1,0.1,0.8]             []                9
    # if reach the target within tolerate
    if len(percent_list) == 0:
        # print(previous_results)
        result_dict.append(previous_results)
        return
    # otherwise, cut impossible branches, check minimum and maximum value acceptable for current percent_list
    percent_sum = percent_list.sum()  # sum up current percent list, **O(n)**, should be optimized by pre-generating a sum list
    value_min = value_list[0]         # minimum value from data list (this problem 0.25)
    value_max = value_list[-1]        # maximum value from data list (this problem 10.0)
    search_min = (target - tolerate_lower - (percent_sum - percent_list[0]) * value_max) / percent_list[0]  # minimum value acceptable as result
    search_max = (target + tolerate_upper - (percent_sum - percent_list[0]) * value_min) / percent_list[0]  # maximum value acceptable as result
    idx_min = np.searchsorted(value_list, search_min, "left")   # index of minimum value (for data list)
    idx_max = np.searchsorted(value_list, search_max, "right")  # index of maximum value (for data list)
    # recursion step
    for i in range(idx_min, idx_max):
        # update result list
        current_results = previous_results + [value_list[i]]
        # remove the current state for variables `percent_list`, and update `target` for next step
        recursion(percent_list[1:], value_list, current_results, target - percent_list[0] * value_list[i], tolerate_lower, tolerate_upper, result_list)
```

To solve this current problem,

```py
result = []
recursion(np.array([0.1, 0.1, 0.8]), np.arange(0.25, 10.25, 0.25), [], 9, 0.5, 0.49999, result)
```

There's totally 4806 possible results. To validate results sum up to about 9 (but could not validate results is plenty enough),

```py
for l in result:
    if not (8.5 <= (np.array([0.1, 0.1, 0.8]) * np.array(l)).sum() < 9.5):
        print("Wrong code!")
```

I think the wrost case complixty is still O(*m*^*n* * *n*), if *m* refers to data list length (0.25, 0.5, ..., 10), and *n* refers to percent list length (0.1, 0.1, 0.8). It should be further optimized to O(*m*^*n* * log(*m*)), to avoid summing up percent list every recursion; and to O(*m*^*n*), if we could fully utilize the nature of arithmetic sequence of the data list.